# What's the difference between MediEvil and MediEvil Resurrection?

Tags: medievil, medievil-resurrection

I own both a PS3 and a PS Vita. The PSN store offers both MediEvil, the original PS1 game, and MediEvil Resurrection, the PSP remake. What are the differences between the two games? Is the remake better than the first game to justify playing it over the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resurrection is a remake with better graphics and has also changes in level design, characters and story elements. Although it has more content that the original, some levels and other content can only be found in the original.

Sources:
http://medievil.wikia.com/wiki/MediEvil:_Resurrection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediEvil:_Resurrection

Answer (score -1):

Resurrection was a disappointing remake that took the fun exploration elements of the original, threw them out of the window and merely replaced them with smoother graphics. Resurrection could be described as a polish and a streamline of the game, but I personally found it lost much of it's charm and several of the best stages.

Comment: The "objective" part of the answer is sort of drowned in your subjective opinnions. Could you edit the answer a bit to make the distinction between the two more clear? Also, more details on the actual changes would greatly improve the answer.